# How to access parameter from nested state in parent state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PnV2erdltuUJsMYFUhR5?p=preview). How i can access 'itemId' parameter in the parent state controller? Parent view must not be reloaded.

```
angular.module('app',['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider){
   $stateProvider.state('step', {
            url: '/orders/:step',
            templateUrl: 'parent.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
                $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
                $scope.step = $stateParams.step;
            }
        })

        .state('step.item', {
            url: '/:itemId',
            templateUrl: 'child.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
                $scope.itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
                $scope.step = $stateParams.step;
            }

        });
}).controller('SimpleController', function($scope, $state){
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  $scope.steps = ["first", "second"];
})
```

I see only two ways:

1. add an service and inject it to both controllers
2. access a parent scope from a child controller and pass a parameter
   But both cause me to add watchers at a parent scope. 
   Maybe i can accomplish it easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to recognize that a parent state's controller runs only once when you enter the subtree of its child states, so switching between its children would not re-run the controller.

This is to say that if you want the `itemId` parameter to always be up to date, you'd need a `$watch` (which you tried to avoid).

For the first time, you could collect the `itemId` like so in the parent's state:

```
$scope.itemId = $state.params.itemId;
```

If you need it to be kept up-to-date, then you'd need to watch for changes, for example:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return $state.params;
}, function(p){
  $scope.itemId = p.itemId;
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4caKic9o4dqH5w9DCk88?p=preview)

Similarly, if you only need to place it in the view, then set `$state` on the scope:

```
$scope.$state = $state;
```

and in the view:

```
<div>parent /orders/{{step}}/{{$state.params.itemId}}</div>
```

**EDIT**:

I guess another way would be to call a scope-exposed function on the parent to update the value. I'm not a fan of such an approach, since it relies on scope inheritance (which is not always the same as state inheritance) and scope inheritance in a large application is difficult to track. But it removes the need for a $watch:

In the parent controller:

```
$scope.updateItemId = function(itemId){
   $scope.itemId = itemId;
};
```

and in the child controller:

```
if ($scope.updateItemId) $scope.updateItemId($stateParams.itemId)
```

Answer (score 3):

I can see, that you've already found your answer, but I would like to show you different approach. And I would even name it as *"the UI-Router built in approach"*.

It has been shown in the [UI-Router example application](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/), where if we go to child state with some ID = 42 [like here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/42) we can also change the other, than the main view *(the `hint` view in this case)*.

There is a [working example with your scenario](http://plnkr.co/edit/TzxHIElMqhRSYDPcHTSM?p=preview), showing that all in action.

What we do use, is the **[Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)**

The parent state, now defines root view, which is injected into unnamed `ui-view=""` inside of the *root/index.html*.

A new `parent.html`

```
<div ui-view="title"></div>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

As we can see, it also contains another view target (than unnamed) - e.g. **`ui-view="title"`** which we fill with another template immediately... in parent state:

```
$stateProvider.state('step', {
  url: '/orders/:step',
  views : {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'parent.html',
    },
    'title@step': {
      templateUrl:'parent_title_view.html',
    }
  }
})
```

And child? It can continue to handle main area... but also can change the title area. Both views are independent, and belong to child.

```
.state('step.item', {
  url: '/:itemId',
  views : {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'child.html',
    },
    'title': {
      templateUrl:'child_title_view.html',
    }
  }
```

So, there are no watchers, nothing... which is not shipped with the `UI-Router` by default. We just adjust many places (views) with the child implementation. We can still provide their content with some defaults in parent..

Check that [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TzxHIElMqhRSYDPcHTSM?p=preview). Hope it will help to see it a bit differently...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will really solve your problem but you can do

```
   $stateProvider.state('step', {
            url: '/orders/:step/:itemId',
            templateUrl: 'parent.html',
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sYCino1V0NOw3qlEALNj?p=preview

This means the parent state will collect the itemID on the way through.

Comment: Forgot to mention. I need to refresh only child view. In your example it will reload parent view.

Comment: Do you kind of want to pass parameters up to the parent from the child? Could you edit your plunkr to illustrate?

Answer (score 0):

include $state in resolve function for parent state

```
.state('parent', {
                url: '/parent',
                controller: 'parentController',
                resolve: {
                params: ['$state', function ($state) {
                            return  $state.params;
                        }]
                }
            })
```

then in parent controller inject the resloved vars

```
app.controller('parentController', ['$scope', 'params',
function ($scope, params) {

  $scope.params = params; 

}]);
```

in this way params available in both child and parent.